# Function to create a tag wrapping a string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I'm trying to create a function that accepts two strings `tambahKata(tag, word)` which will return `<tag>word</tag>`. For example:

```
>>> tambahKata(keyboard, mouse)
'<keyboard>mouse</keyboard>'
```

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
def tambahKata(tag,kata):
    tag = "<",tag,">"
    return tag
    tambahKata("html","saya adalah programmer")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), if you are using Python 3.6+:

```
def tambahKata(tag,kata):
    return f"<{tag}>{kata}</{tag}>"
```

Usage:

```
>>> tambahKata("keyboard","mouse")
'<keyboard>mouse</keyboard>'
```

Alternatively, below Python 3.6 you could just construct the string like so:

```
def tambahKata(tag,kata):
    start_tag = "<" + tag + ">"
    end_tag = "</" + tag + ">"
    return start_tag + kata + end_tag
```